# My Output is Wonky

Tags: c

So basically I want to read a text file with numbers in it that represent and auction, how many items are being sold, how many offers there are, and the actual offers. What I have to do is output the highest offer as the sold price but for some reason my program only prints out the last price and not the highest.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//main function
int main() {
    //Declaring variables and arrays
    float   numberBids[15], max, sum = 0 ,numberAuc;
    float   bids[10];
    int     i, y, j= 0, x, z = 0;
    char    filename[100]= "";

    //User puts in filename
    printf("Please enter the name of the file.\n");
    scanf("%s",&filename);

    //Opens file
    FILE * finp=fopen(filename,"r");

    //Scans info
    fscanf(finp, "%f" , &numberAuc);

    for(i=0; i < numberAuc; i++){

    fscanf(finp, "%f",&numberBids[i]);
        for (x = 0; x < numberBids[i];x++)

        {

        fscanf(finp, "%f", &bids[i]);
        max = bids[i];
        }
    //Replaces old max with newer one if larger
    for(j; j<numberBids; j++)
        if (bids[i]>max)
        max = bids[i];

    }

    //Sum
    sum += bids[i];
    //Print out to the output
    for ( y = 0; y <  numberAuc; y++ )
    {
        y = y+ 1;
        printf("Auction %d was sold for $%.2f\n", y, bids[z]);
        z++;
        y = y- 1;
    }
    //Close
    fclose(finp);

return 0;

}
```

And here is what the text file says

```
5

4

100 500 250 300

1

700

3

300 150 175
2

920 680

8

20 10 15 25 50 30 19 23
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't reassigning the actual `bid` amount. You have *a lot* of unused and meaningless statements in the code (I'll update in a bit with more), but the main part is that you aren't really doing anything with your `max` variable.

Your code (with some added comments):

```
for (x = 0; x < numberBids[i];x++){
    /*Why are you using the `i` variable in a loop of `x`?*/
    fscanf(finp, "%f", &bids[i]);
    /*Setting the max to each as it's read in - doesn't do anything except waste cycles*/
    max = bids[i];
}

/*
* You are comparing j to a pointer, numberBids here.
* You're saying: "while j is less than some memory address"
*/
for(j; j<numberBids; j++){
    /*
    * You aren't using the j variable anyways, so you're comparing the same 
    * two numbers here every iteration (max and bid[i], which doesn't change
    * until the next auction since you are using `i`) 
    */
    if (bids[i]>max){
        max = bids[i];
    }
}
```

From what I can tell, your code only needs to do the following:

```
for each auction:
    get number of bids
    get bid amounts
    get the maximum of these bids
```

So the code should look like:

```
/*for each auction*/
for(int i=0; i < numberAuc; i++) {

    /*get number of bids*/
    fscanf(finp, "%f", &numberBids[i]);

    float max = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < numberBids[i]; x++){
        /*get bid amounts*/
        fscanf(finp, "%f", &bids[x]);

        /*find the maximum*/
        max = bids[x] > max ? bids[x] : max;
    }

    printf("Auction %d was sold for $%.2f\n", i, max);
}
```

#### [Full code file (with all fixes mentioned below)](http://pastie.org/10943926)

---

### Other notes (especially on code style/readability):

- Stay consistent with curly braces. Some of yours were on the next line with others on the same line as the statement needing to be scoped (for loops, etc). Also, it may seem cleaner, but personally I recommend using curly braces around one line statements like your `for`/`if`. If you need to expand it later, they're there, but also it can increase readability if you properly align...
- It's okay to declare variables in the scope you're using them instead of all at the top. Compilers these days are smart enough to optimize initialization, so you don't need to be worried about creating 100500 `int`s in a loop, and predeclaring to reserve space isn't much of a worry these days either. This is something else to be consistent about -- so if you insist on putting declarations from all scopes at the top of a function, do it with everything.
- Especially since you're a beginner -- treat compiler warnings like errors (in fact compilers have flags to automatically do that, to force you to fix them). It would have saved you some problems in the code (like comparing an iterating integer to a pointer).
- The way you get the filename is a method that's considered unsafe (`scanf`).

Do this instead:

```
char filename[100];
fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), stdin);
```

Using `fgets` to get user input from stdin has one caveat - it includes the `\n` newline from pressing ENTER. Just terminate the string at that symbol:

```
unsigned len = strlen(filename)-1;
filename[len] = '\0';
```

- When opening a file, do some sort of error handling, in case `fopen` returns NULL. If it doesn't open correctly, nothing else in this program can occur since it all relies on content from the file, and also you'd be throwing a null pointer around.
- Lastly, use `int` to store integers. `float` works, but floating point numbers can be... fickle. `numberBids[15]`, `bids[10]`, and `numberAuc` all can and should be integers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some modifications in your code which produce the following output:

```
Auction 1 was sold for $500.00
Auction 2 was sold for $700.00
Auction 3 was sold for $300.00
Auction 4 was sold for $920.00
Auction 5 was sold for $50.00
```

The code creates the input file and doesn't ask the user for input, for sake of testing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//main function
int main() {
    //Declaring variables and arrays
    int   numberBids[15], numberAuc;
    float max/*,sum = 0 ,*/;
    float   bids[10];
    int     i, /*y,*/ j= 0, x/*, z = 0*/;
    char    filename[100]= "test.txt";

    FILE* ftest = fopen(filename, "w+");
    fprintf(ftest, "5\n");//Number auctions
    fprintf(ftest, "4\n");//Number bids for auction 1
    fprintf(ftest, "100 500 250 300\n");
    fprintf(ftest, "1\n");
    fprintf(ftest, "700\n");
    fprintf(ftest, "3\n");
    fprintf(ftest, "300 150 175\n");
    fprintf(ftest, "2\n");
    fprintf(ftest, "920 680\n");
    fprintf(ftest, "8\n");
    fprintf(ftest, "20 10 15 25 50 30 19 23\n");
    fclose(ftest);

    //User puts in filename
    /* We temporary skip this ...
    printf("Please enter the name of the file.\n");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    */
    //Opens file
    FILE * finp=fopen(filename,"r");

    //Scans info
    fscanf(finp, "%d" , &numberAuc);

    for(int i=0; i < numberAuc; i++){
    fscanf(finp, "%d",&numberBids[i]);
        max=0;
        for (int x = 0; x < numberBids[i];x++)
        {
        fscanf(finp, "%f", &bids[i]);
        if(bids[i]>max)max = bids[i];
        }
    //Replaces old max with newer one if larger
        /*
    for(int j=0; j<numberBids; j++)
    {
        if (bids[i]>max)
        max = bids[i];
    }*/
    printf("Auction %d was sold for $%.2f\n", i+1, max);
    }

    /*
    //Sum
    sum += bids[i];
    //Print out to the output
    for ( y = 0; y <  numberAuc; y++ )
    {
        y = y+ 1;
        printf("Auction %d was sold for $%.2f\n", y, bids[z]);
        z++;
        y = y- 1;
    }*/
    //Close
    fclose(finp);

return 0;

}
```